# Получить данные с Firebase, Android studio

Tags: android, firebase

здравствуйте, такая ситуация, занёс в базу информацию (код ниже) получил её в другом активити в recycleView с применением адаптера (без кода), а теперь нужно нажав на итем получить определённую информацию с сервера в новое активити, подскажите как, может адаптер какой

```
buttonCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(validateForm())
            {
                String start=startView.getText().toString().trim();
                String finish=finishView.getText().toString().trim();
                String mdate=currentDateTime.getText().toString().trim();

                // create user object and set all the properties
                KatkaInformation katka = new KatkaInformation();
                katka.setPointStart(start);
                katka.setPointFinish(finish);
                katka.setDate(mdate);
                ;
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
                {
                    // save the user at UserNode under user UID
                    databaseReference.child("Katka List").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(katka, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if(databaseError==null)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data is saved successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Васинтересует как данные меж активити передавать?

Comment: да, мне нужно просто при нажатии на итем в recyclerView открыть активити с отдельными скажем так данными которые уже занесены в firebase

Comment: Вы описали несколько задач, не одну. Одно дело передать данные меж активити и совсем другое - отобразить что-то из Firebase. Выберите что-то одно) У нас правило - один вопрос - одна проблема)

Comment: ладно) тогда как отобразить данные из firebase? если уже есть переход между активити

Comment: Как-то так:

`databaseReference.child("Katka List").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addSingleValueEventListener(...);`